# No matching constructor for class initialization

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have this class :

```
class instaStalkPanel : public wxPanel {
private:
    
public:
    instaStalkPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, wxPoint &pos, wxSize &size, long style, const wxString &name);
    
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

Now I'm trying to initialize a pointer variable of this class like this, in another class called instaStalkFrame :

```
mainPanel = new instaStalkPanel(this, ID_PANEL_MAIN, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, "panel");
```

The error it gives me :

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'instaStalkPanel'

Any ideas why this happens ?

- Note:

The constructor function :

```
instaStalkPanel::instaStalkPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, wxPoint &pos, wxSize &size, long style, const wxString &name) : wxPanel(parent, id, pos, size, style, name){
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind non-const references (`pos` and `size`) to const objects.
Make the parameters `const wxPoint&` and `const wxSize&`.